# Pygame Error Help - pygame.error: video system not initialized

Tags: python, pygame

```
def eventLoop():
pygame.display.update()
for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == QUIT:
        pygame.quit()
        sys.exit
```

When running my game (calling the eventLoop() function) I get this error:

```
File "C:\Users\Slav\Desktop\project\test.py", line 342, in eventLoop
pygame.display.update()
pygame.error: video system not initialized
```

Pygame is initialized in this function here (before eventLoop() is defined):

```
def initialise(window_width, window_height, window_name, window_colour):
    pygame.init()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((window_width, window_height), 0, 32)
    pygame.display.set_caption(window_name)
    screen.fill(window_colour)
    return screen
```

The initialise function is called here :

```
if show_generation:
    screen = initialise(width, height, "Maze Generator", BLACK)
maze = generate_maze(show_generation, gen_choice)

if show_solving and not show_generation:
    screen = initialise(width, height, "Maze Generator", BLACK)
visited, num_items = solve_maze(sol_choice)
```

The show generation / show solving is a variable taken from from 2 check boxes in the app whether the user wants to just show the maze generation and / or maze solving

The eventLoop() function is called when the user has chosen to both show and solve the generated maze (right at the end of my code)

```
if show_generation or show_solving:
     while True:
         eventLoop()
```

Full Error :

```
x_cells: 2 
y_cells: 2 
show_generation:  True 
show_solving: True 
save_image: True
Running Kruskal�s algorithm
Running depth first search

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Ray\Desktop\project\pygame.py", line 701, in <module>
eventLoop()
File "C:\Users\Ray\Desktop\project\pygame.py", line 342, in eventLoop
pygame.display.update()
pygame.error: video system not initialized
[Finished in 4.783s]
```

Comment: Welcome to SO.  There's not much to go by with these two snippets of code.  How are you actually executing those functions?  And in what order?

Comment: Changed post accordingly.

Comment: The problem with how you're presenting your code is not in sequence.  Can you please re-edit your post such that you are presenting the code as is?  What is ```show_generation``` and ```show_solving```?

Comment: Hopefully that gives you a better idea ?

Comment: Please show what is printed out before the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is in the the `eventLoop()`

```py
def eventLoop():
pygame.display.update()
for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == QUIT:
        pygame.quit()
        sys.exit
```

Instead of if `if event.type == QUIT:` it should be `if event.type == pygame.QUIT:`
Also instead of `sys.exit` it should be `sys.exit()`

So the `eventLoop()` should look like :

```py
def eventLoop():
pygame.display.update()
for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
        pygame.quit()
        sys.exit()
```

Comment: `event.type == QUIT` is not the problem. But the `sys.exit`-part is because `pygame.quit()` will deinitialize the pygame module, and since the loop is not stopped, a call to `pygame.display.update()` will fail.

Comment: @sloth I agree.

Answer (score 0):

take away the pygame.quit() I think it fixed my problem.